# RStudio encounters fatal error and restarts on EVERY error in R

Tags: java, r, windows, rstudio

I recently changed employers and only have local administrator privileges on a virtual machine running Windows. I installed R and RStudio, both of which work fine, UNTIL I commit an error—any error. Once that happens, RStudio gives the dreaded "fatal error" message and restarts. The reprex is simple. Start RStudio and type `as.Date('a')`. This will give an error and cause Rstudio to shut down. It appears to be a java error with the key issue being `(TypeError) : Cannot read property 'M' of null;`. There have been [many requests](https://community.rstudio.com/search?q=%60(TypeError)%20%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20%27M%27%20of%20null%3B%60%20) for help in RStudio's support forum with similar crashes which have not been answered, which is why I'm duplicating the question here.

Session Info and RStudio crash logs posted below

### SessionInfo

```
R Under development (unstable) (2022-02-04 r81652 ucrt)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.utf8  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.utf8    LC_MONETARY=English_United States.utf8
[4] LC_NUMERIC=C                           LC_TIME=English_United States.utf8    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] compiler_4.2.0 tools_4.2.0
```

### RStudio Logs

```
2022-02-09T17:56:41.573000Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] WARNING findProgramOnPath returns wrong result: C:\Users\AVRAHA~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe != C:/Users/AvrahamAdler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::FilePath __cdecl rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &) src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:1206
2022-02-09T17:56:41.573000Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] WARNING findProgramOnPath returns wrong result: C:\Users\AVRAHA~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe != C:/Users/AvrahamAdler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::FilePath __cdecl rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &) src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:1206
2022-02-09T17:56:41.577000Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] WARNING findProgramOnPath returns wrong result: C:\Users\AVRAHA~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe != C:/Users/AvrahamAdler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::FilePath __cdecl rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &) src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:1206
2022-02-09T17:56:41.577000Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] WARNING findProgramOnPath returns wrong result: C:\Users\AVRAHA~1\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe != C:/Users/AvrahamAdler/AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/pdflatex.exe; LOGGED FROM: class rstudio::core::FilePath __cdecl rstudio::session::module_context::findProgram(const class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > &) src/cpp/session/SessionModuleContext.cpp:1206
2022-02-09T17:56:43.063059Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-AvrahamAdler): (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'M' of null;|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditor.java#4487::setScrollSpeed|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#46::monitor|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#70::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/SchedulerImpl.java#140::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.java#41::viewDataMap|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
2022-02-09T17:56:43.063059Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-AvrahamAdler): (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'M' of null;|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditor.java#4487::setScrollSpeed|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#46::monitor|||org/rstudio/studio/client/workbench/views/source/editors/text/AceEditorMonitor.java#70::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/SchedulerImpl.java#140::execute|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#306::apply|||com/google/gwt/core/client/impl/Impl.java#345::entry0|||rstudio-0.js#-1::eval|||com/google/gwt/cell/client/AbstractEditableCell.java#41::viewDataMap|||Client-ID: 33e600bb-c1b1-46bf-b562-ab5cba070b0e|||User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0  Win64  x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) QtWebEngine/5.12.8 Chrome/69.0.3497.128 Safari/537.36
```

Comment: Maybe try another version of RStudio? One you using is unstable.

Comment: Hello, @talex. The version of **Rstudio** I am running is the most recent release version---2021.09.2+382. It is stable. What (unstable) refers to is the R version. It is called unstable as I am building R-dev-UCRT on source from Windows (what will be 4.2.0) with Tomas Kalibera's new toolchain, and compiling R-devel from source on windows always names itself as (unstable).. It passes `make check-devel` so I am not worried about that. I have been using "unstable" versions of R since before 4.0.0 was released, as I compile from source on Windows. Thanks.

Comment: I'd download a nightly build of RStudio.  There's a news item https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/blob/6ae74d7e4fa1216414e93b5b7ea993d496028ead/version/news/NEWS-2022.02.0-prairie-trillium.md for a newer version, claiming "RStudio now supports the experimental UTF-8 UCRT builds of R (#9824)".

Comment: @user2554330 I think that did it! I still see an error in the logs `(2022-02-09T18:44:26.986463Z [rsession-AvrahamAdler] ERROR CLIENT EXCEPTION (rsession-AvrahamAdler): (TypeError) : Cannot read property 'O' of null;` But RStudio isn't crashing!! If you post this as an answer I'd be happy to accept it. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio is about to come out with version 2022.02.0.  As I write this it hasn't been released, but you can get daily builds from https://dailies.rstudio.com/ .  The NEWS for that release includes the statement

> RStudio now supports the experimental UTF-8 UCRT builds of R (#9824)

so it should fix your problems (and according to a comment, it did).  However, do pay attention to the warning at the top of that web page:

> Daily builds are intended for testing purposes, and are not recommended for general use. For stable builds, please visit rstudio.com.